# gnuplot: the "sum [<var> = <start>:<end>] <expression>" strategy

Tags: python, sum, gnuplot

In the following script, I would like to plot `y(x)`:

[image]

and this function `u(x)`:

[image]

**EDIT**

Plotting `y(x)` is easy, but I am having problems to plot the function `u(x)`.

`u(x)` is just the same function as `y(x)`, but summing every step.

Therefore, in order to plot `u(x)`, I have tried the `sum [<var> = <start>:<end>] <expression>` strategy. I have implemented this notation as:

`replot sum[x=1:6] y(x) with line lt -1 lw 1 lc 2 title "u(x)"`

in the following script:

```
 #

 set ylabel "y" font  ", 20"
 set xlabel 'x' font  ", 20"


 set format y "%9.4f"
 set xrange [1:6]

 set yrange [0:20]
 set xtics font ", 15"
 set ytics font ", 15"


 set key font ",17" # Changes the font of the letters of the legend

 y(x) = (2*x)/(x**2)
 plot y(x) with line lt -1 lw 1 lc 1 title "y(x)"
 replot sum[x=1:6] y(x) with line lt -1 lw 1 lc 2 title "u(x)"


 pause -1
 set term post enh color eps
 set output "y_x.eps"
 replot
```

I am not sure if the `sum[x=1:6] y(x)` strategy is indeed plotting `u(x)`.

In order to check this, we can do the following:

we know that:

[image]

So, what is the value in gnuplot for `u(6)`? If you run that script, you get:

[image]

zooming:

I see that `u(6)` is reaching the value of `2.0000`, and not `3.5835`.

This makes me think that the `replot sum[x=1:6] u(x)` is not plotting u(x_i) (second formula)

How could I plot `u(x)` ?.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Running `replot sum[i=1:6] y(i)` in this script:

```
set ylabel "y" font  ", 20"
set xlabel 'x' font  ", 20"


 set format y "%9.4f"

 set xrange [1:6]

 set yrange [0:20]
 set xtics font ", 15"
 set ytics font ", 15"


 set key font ",17" # Changes the font of the letters of the legend

 y(x) = (2*x)/(x**2)
 plot y(x) with line lt -1 lw 1 lc 1 title "y(x)"


 replot sum[i=1:6] y(i) with line lt -1 lw 1 lc 2 title "u(x)"

 pause -1
 set term post enh color eps
 set output "y_x.eps"
 replot
```

produces the following: `u(6) = 3.000`:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Using `y(x) = (2.*x)/(x**2)` or `y(x) = (2.*x)/(x**2.)`, I get `u(6) = 4.9`:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 4**

Making:

```
N=100
replot sum[i=0:N-1] y(1. + (i+0.5)*5./N)*5./N with line lt -1 lw 1 lc 5 title "sum(x)"
```

produces a constant (cyan line) `y=3.58`. This is the result of the numerical approximation of the summation.

[image]

What I really want to achieve is to plot the function `u(x)` for all the values of `x_{i}`... in which at every step `i`, the summation over all the previous steps is performed, and a new value of `u` is generated. I would like to plot the function `u(x)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, what is actually plotted as `u(x)` is just `6*y(x)`, you can check that if you replace in your script the line

```
plot y(x) with line lt -1 lw 1 lc 1 title "y(x)"
```

with

```
plot 6*y(x) with line lt -1 lw 1 lc 1 title "y(x)"
```

that the line will then coincide with `u(x)`.

Also, note that the function `y(x)` is not integrable in the interval `[0, 6]` since it behaves at `0` as `1/x` (in your formula, you would obtain expression `ln(0)`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I agree that what is actually plotted as `u(x)` is just `6*y(x)`. For some reason I don't understand, this is happening indeed. I also agree about the integration limits. See the edited version: It is still unknown how `u(x)` could actually be plotted. Thanks

Comment: I have to admit that the definition of `u(x)` is not very clear to me. Is it supposed to be a constant approximation of the integral calculated with rectangle rule? If so, you could use `sum[i=1:5] y(i)` - the original problem arises because the summation variable `x` clashes with the "standard" independent variable used for plotting... However, the approximation will be rather poor, one would need higher order rule or more points...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
This is just an example of what I am trying to accomplish: be able to plot a formula that has summations inside. The real formula I want to plot is a bit complicated. In order to simplify the question, I just took an example, which is the first formula, `y(x)`, that can easily be plotted (red line). Then, I imagined another function `u(x)` that is just `y(x)` but with one summation inside. I am trying to plot this `u(x)` function.

Comment: This simple case is also good, because I can check if the plot is OK by comparison with the result of that integral.  I know that that approximation it is rather poor. If the plot of `u(x)` is correct, then `u(6)` would reach a similar value to `3.58` (the result of the exact integral).  I have implemented the `replot sum[i=1:6] y(i) with line lt -1 lw 1 lc 2 title "u(x)"` strategy you kindly suggested, and I get a value of `u(6) = 3.000` (see **EDIT 2**).

Comment: Therefore, that green line `u(x)` is not an accurate description of the function `u(x)`. Is there a way of increasing the i-step? Something like `sum[i=1:step:6]` does not work. Thank you very much

Comment: you get `u(6) = 3.000` because `y(x) = (2*x)/(x**2)` in combination with `sum[i=1:6] y(i)` is done in integer arithmetic - use `y(x) = (2.*x)/(x**2)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have used `y(x) = (2.*x)/(x**2)` and `y(x) = (2.*x)/(x**2.)` and I get `u(6) = 4.9` (See **EDIT 3**) instead of something similar to `3.58`

Comment: Do you see what I mean? The last comment shows it is not a matter of integer arithmetic combination...

Comment: no, not only, it's also how you are calculating the approximation to the integral - with rectangle rule on the interval `[1,6]` and `N` integration points, the correct prescription is `sum[i=0:N-1] y(1. + i*5./N)*5./N`, you can check that `print sum[i=0:99] f(1. + i*5./100)*5./100` gives `~3.62559`. However, even midpoint rule `sum[i=0:N-1] y(1. + (i+0.5)*5./N)*5./N` performs here much better - with `N=100`, it gives `~3.5833`...

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation on how to correctly approximate the integral numerically. I highly appreciated it. `replot sum[i=0:N-1] y(1. + (i+0.5)*5./N)*5./N` gives obviously a line, which is the result of the final summation, `3.5833`. See **EDIT 4** : However, what I would like to achieve is to plot `u(x)` at every value of `x_{i}`, in which at every step `i`, the summation over all the previous steps is performed, and a new value of `u` is generated. Thank you very much